# The C++ detection idiom is not working as expected in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 CTP

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17

I'm playing with the [proposal of standard library support for the C++ detection idiom](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf) and compiled the following code with the *Microsoft C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23725 for x64*:

```
#include <iostream>


template<class...>
using void_t = void;

template<class, template<class> class, class = void_t<>>
struct detect : std::false_type { };

template<class T, template<class> class Operation>
struct detect<T, Operation, void_t<Operation<T>>> : std::true_type { };


template<class T>
using bar_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().bar());

template<class T>
using bar_int_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(0));

template<class T>
using bar_string_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(""));


struct foo
{
    int bar() { return 0; }
    int bar(int) { return 0; }
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << detect<foo, bar_t>{} << std::endl;
    std::cout << detect<foo, bar_int_t>{} << std::endl;
    std::cout << detect<foo, bar_string_t>{} << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output would be

```
1
1
0
```

but it is

```
1
1
1
```

What is going wrong? I've made a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2265919c09a2379e) (with exactly the same code) where the output is as expected.

Comment: It's because of SFINAE support absense. You can choose Clang in Visual Studio targets (supported since VS 2015 Update 1).

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ has a limited support for expression SFINAE, however, I think it should work with a function return type. So, instead you can try the below implementation:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename, template <typename> class>
auto detect_impl(char) -> std::false_type;

template <typename T, template <typename> class Operation>
auto detect_impl(int) -> decltype(void_t<Operation<T>>(), std::true_type{});

template <typename T, template <typename> class Operation>
using detect = decltype(detect_impl<T, Operation>(0));
```

*(Tested on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)*