# MSVC - Member detection with void_t doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++

I've run into this the other day.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type; };
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

template <class, class = void>
struct is_func_chrend_ : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_func_chrend_<T, ::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().NextTile())>> : std::true_type {};

template <class = void, class = void>
struct is_addable : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_addable<T, ::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())>> : std::true_type {};

int main() {
    cout << is_addable<int>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Displays 0 when compiled in MSVC, 1 if compiled in clang or gcc. 
Completely removing `is_func_chrend_` makes `is_addable` work properly again.

Makeshift `void_t` used for only C++11-compliant compilers.

Comment: didn't investigate your code, but VS doesn't fully implement expression SFINAE

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/q/35669239/3953764

Comment: You probably need the absolute latest MSVC for this to work. I get a `1` with VS2015 SP3.

Comment: @BoPersson I get 0 on both VS2015 and VS 15, both fully updated as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC has yet to ship a C++11 compliant compiler.

Their biggest remaining problem is `decltype` being used in a SFINAE context.

They improve the situation regularly, making more and more `decltype` cases work, but it is not reliable.

The way in which it is broken often generates false positives and false negatives when things go wrong, and the failures are non-local in that how you previously used the SFINAE expression can change how it succeeds or fails next time.

You simply cannot safely use decltype based SFINAE in MSVC, unless you carefully decode what your specific version of MSVC can handle, and never leave those bounds.  I personally find their descriptions of what works and what doesn't insufficiently clear to feel I can relyably use it.